# WooCommerce - Order overview, change column placement

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce

I just want two of the columns to switch place, and it should be very easy - yet in woocommerce im not quite sure how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `manage_edit-orders_columns` action hook in your `functions.php` or in your custom plugin.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-orders_columns', 'changecolumnorder' );
function changecolumnorder( $columns ){
    // one option is to "recreate" the whole array but you can do it with array_slice() function as well

    // remove Date column first 
    unset( $columns['order_date'] );
    // and add it into the correct place

    return array_slice( $columns, 0, 3, true )
    + array( 'order_date' => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ) )
    + array_slice( $columns, 3, NULL, true );

}
```

I see suggestions in the other answers to edit woocommerce plugin files. Please do not do that! Always use hooks. More hooks that allows to customize WooCommerce columns you can find [here](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/columns.html#columns_hooks)

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/get_columns/

Extend WP List Table class and inside it you override the function

like below with your columns in your desired order

```
function get_columns() {

        return $columns = array(
        'title'        => 'Title',
      'properties'    => 'Properties',
      'stock'=>'Stock',
      'price' => 'Price',
      'published'    => 'Published'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-post-type.php

```
public function shop_order_columns( $existing_columns ) {
        $columns                     = array();
        $columns['cb']               = $existing_columns['cb'];
        $columns['order_status']     = '<span class="status_head tips" data-tip="' . esc_attr__( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ) . '">' . esc_attr__( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
        $columns['order_title']      = __( 'Order', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['order_date']       = __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['billing_address']  = __( 'Billing', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['shipping_address'] = __( 'Ship to', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['customer_message'] = '<span class="notes_head tips" data-tip="' . esc_attr__( 'Customer Message', 'woocommerce' ) . '">' . esc_attr__( 'Customer Message', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
        $columns['order_notes']      = '<span class="order-notes_head tips" data-tip="' . esc_attr__( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '">' . esc_attr__( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
        $columns['order_items']      = __( 'Purchased', 'woocommerce' );

        $columns['order_total']      = __( 'Total', 'woocommerce' );
        $columns['order_actions']    = __( 'Actions', 'woocommerce' );

        return $columns;
    }
```

replace this code with from line no 264 to 280
check screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/04961cfedc

Comment: Do not modify Plugin files directly as these modifications will be lost when a Plugin update is applied. Use the available Filters to override Admin Order columns.